# Adding to WHERE clause conditions using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a stored procedure that accepts an optional @ID param.  When the param is passed in, I want the WHERE statement to include something like id = @ID, otherwise, when @ID is null, I don't want it to be filtered.

For example:

```
@ID BIGINT = NULL

SELECT * from myTable
WHERE 
CASE
    WHEN @ID IS NOT NULL THEN mytable.id = @ID
END
```

I am running this in SQL server 2016 and it says bad syntax near mytable.id = @ID.  Can CASE be used in this way or should I try a different SQL method for this?

The only other option I considered to accomplish this was by using IF conditions in my stored procedure, but that didn't seem possible either based on my searches.

Comment: Can you change your query to @ ID BIGINT = NULL

SELECT * from myTable
WHERE 
     @ ID IS  NULL or mytable.id = @ ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CASE is an expression, not a statement. It is not used to control flow like this and it will not work.

Your logic would need to be something like this.

```
Where mytable.id = ISNULL(@ID, mytable.id)
```

I should caution you that this pattern can lead to some poor performance. For a more detailed explanation and some other options you should check out this article. http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: I will mark correct because this is the closest answer to my question that directly answers it.  The more efficient solution requires quite a rework.

Comment: Actually if this is a stored procedure you could simply use RECOMPILE hint (as long compiling the procedure isn't a big hit) and you should continue to get pretty good execution plans. Gail discusses this in her article I linked.

Answer (score 0):

A *bad-performance* approach would be:

```
WHERE ISNULL(@ID,mytable.id) = mytable.id
```

A better-performance approach would be:

```
 if(@ID IS NULL)
   select * from ... without the WHERE condition
else
    do your query with the condition mytable.id = @ID
```

Or build the query dynamically in the stored proc and execute it through `sp_executesql` passing parameters

Note: If the table is small enough, stick to simplicity and use the first option.